# Python tuple key in dictionary not able to fetch

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary in python having tuple as key and value as int. It looks like:

```
{('class1','name1'):3,('class1','name2'):3,('class2','name1'):1,('class2','name2'):2}
```

I want to find name wise difference of values from class1 to class 2. Eg:

```
{('class1','name1'):2,('class1','name2'):1}
```

Can you please help me? I am new in python and don't want to iterate over list. Is there any pythonic way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `collections.Counter`:

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

```
>>> c = Counter(a=4, b=2, c=0, d=-2)
>>> d = Counter(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
>>> c.subtract(d)
>>> c
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 0, 'c': -3, 'd': -6})
```

In your case you can use something like this

```
>>> d = {('class1','name1'):3,('class1','name2'):3,('class2','name1'):1,('class2','name2'):2}
>>> dict1 = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k[0] == "class1"}
>>> dict2 = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if k[1] == "class2"}
# in Python2.6 and earlier: dict([(k,v) for k,v in d.items() if blah])
>>> difference = dict(Counter(dict1) - Counter(dict2))
>>> difference
{('class1', 'name2'): 1, ('class1', 'name1'): 2}
```

Comment: But I don't have two separate dictionaries. I have all my entries in one dictionary only. Do you know any way in which I can create such two dictionary by my given data in question? How can I make such query in key tuple?